# layout_weight in android layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have this layout file from Chapter 13 of [Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321804333):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/armstrong_on_moon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hellomoon_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hellomoon_playButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hellomoon_play"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hellomoon_stopButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hellomoon_stop"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And it results in a layout that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0ChY.jpg). What I do not understand is how the `TableRow` shows up in the layout at all since its `layout_weight` is 0 and the `ImageView`'s `layout_weight` is 1. My understanding is that the way `layout_weight` works is it will first respect the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of each element, and then divide up the remaning space between the elements based on `layout_weight`. But since the `ImageView` has `match_parent` for both its `layout_width` and `layout_height`, shouldn't it take up the whole screen and then leave nothing left to divide with the `TableRow`? I believe that the `TableRow` also has `match_parent` for both its `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes since it inherited them from `TableLayout`, but since it came second I thought the `ImageView` would dominate the screen. Also, even if the the `ImageView` shouldn't take up the whole screen, aren't the `layout_weights` saying that the `ImageView` should get 100% of the remaining space and the `TableRow` should get 0%? Additionally, when I increase the `layout_weight` of the `TableRow`, the `TableRow` just gets pushed further and further off the screen as it increases more-- but I thought that this should increase the space the `TableRow` takes up on the screen. Can anyone explain what I'm misunderstanding here.

In case it helps, my understanding for `layout_weight` comes from this example in the book:

```
**How android:layout_weight works**
...

LinearLayout makes two passes to set the width of a view. In the first pass, LinearLayout looks at layout_width (or layout_height, for vertical orientation). The value for layout_width for both the Button and CheckBox is now wrap_content, so each view will get only enough space to draw itself (Figure 8.12).

...

In the next pass, LinearLayout allocates any extra space based on the values for layout_weight.
```

Answer (score 2):

The TableRow has a height of `wrap_content`. This is enforced by the `TableLayout`, as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html):

> The children of a TableLayout cannot specify the layout_width attribute. Width is always MATCH_PARENT. However, the layout_height attribute can be defined by a child; default value is WRAP_CONTENT. If the child is a TableRow, then the height is always WRAP_CONTENT.

`TableLayout` and `TableRow` are both `LinearLayout` subclasses, but I experienced the same strange behaviors when I created a layout like the one in your post. Browsing the source of `TableLayout` and `TableRow`, it's not immediately clear to me what causes this (clearly there's some overridden logic in the measuring code, but that's not really satisfactory to figure out things like column spans and to adjust column widths and such, but I'd have to dig more to figure out what's going on).

Unless this example actually needs/uses some of the special behaviors of `TableLayout` and `TableRow`, I would advise just using `LinearLayout`s instead for the sake of clarity. The presence of `layout_weight` with those two views is frankly confusing and clearly doesn't behave as expected. In either case, you don't even need the `layout_weight="0", whether you use two`LinearLayout`s or keep the example as-is.